# Visual Studio 2017 losing references of WPF when pulling from repository

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, devexpress

I'm working on a WPF project in which I'm started to use the DevExpress library for WPF controls. I had added a few of dlls to the project for the controls to work and in my computer the project is working fine. I had pushed my project to the remote server using git. The problem comes when my coworkers want to pull my changes. When they pull the references appears as lost like this:

[image]

I have checked the properties of the dlls in my coworkers project and the `Path` appears empty and the `Resolve` property as False. I think this problem is because I have added the dlls from a folder directly in my hard drive and not inside the project. The Path that appears when I check the properties of the references in my project is this: `C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress 20.1\Components\Bin\Framework\DevExpress.Data.v20.1.dll`.
Is this the reason why my coworkers project doesn't get the references? Where I have to save the dlls inside the projects to reference them in the project and still works when we deploy a executable version of the project?

Comment: DevExpress has an installer that adds the libraries to the GAC, if you and your coworkers use it there should be no problem.

Comment: @Gusman sorry for the ignorance but what is GAC?

Comment: [Global Assembly Cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/gac)

Comment: @Gusman Do you know how to use this installer? I have installed Component Installer and Desktop Products Installer but none of these looks to affect my project

Comment: From what I see you are using the XPF controls for WPF. First, you should remove the references to the DLL's that you added. Then, if it installed correctly the controls should appear in the control toolbox. If they don't appear then you can right-click the toolbox in an empty space and select "choose items", it will show a new form with many tabs, in the one named "WPF components" search for the DevExpress ones that you need to use and they will be added to the toolbox. Once you add the controls to your app from the toolbox the references will be automatically added to your project.

Comment: @Gusman I have done this and work as you say but the dlls still taking the same reference from my local hard drive as specified in the question.

Comment: Even if they seem to take the same reference they aren't. Yes, they use the same files but the stored references in the project are different, instead of pointing to concrete files point to the GAC. Try to push it to your GIT server and check if it works in your coworkers computers, it should.

Comment: @Gusman they have done the pull but still have the reference as lost. They have to install the DevExpess controls in them computers?

Comment: Yes, that's the first I said that they need to do... *DevExpress has an installer that adds the libraries to the GAC, if you and your coworkers use it there should be no problem.*

Comment: Did you upload the DLLs to the repository? Or how are your coworkers supposed to get them? You should either include them in the repository or your coworkers will need to get them from somewhere else, like for example DevExpress' official product channels.